# i want to execute this code and output in default output format using php?

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$field_format = array('format'=>"date('Y-m-d',strtotime(created_date))");//array define here
echo 'default output '.date('Y-m-d',strtotime('26-09-2016'));
echo nl2br('<br/>');
echo nl2br('<br/>');
if (array_key_exists('format', $field_format)) {
    $value_in_format = $field_format['format'];
    $value_in_format = preg_replace('/created_date/','26-09-2016', $value_in_format);
```

> // printed var_dump format

```
    var_dump(preg_replace('/created_date/','26-09-2016', $value_in_format));
    echo nl2br('<br/>');
    echo nl2br('<br/>');
    echo  $value_in_format;
```

> // i want this output should be same as default output

```
    echo nl2br('<br/>');
    echo nl2br('<br/>');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to do, but your output is in another format because of the preg_replace..If you change your preg_replace with this line:

```
$value_in_format = preg_replace('/created_date/','2016-09-26', $value_in_format);
```

then your default output will be the same with the "$value_in_format" output.

Update:

```
<?php 
$field_format = array('format'=>"date('Y-m-d',strtotime(created_date))");//array define here
echo 'default output '.date('Y-m-d',strtotime('26-09-2016'));
echo nl2br('<br/>');
echo nl2br('<br/>');
if (array_key_exists('format', $field_format)) {
    $value_in_format = $field_format['format'];
    $value_in_format = preg_replace('/created_date/','"26-09-2016"', $value_in_format);
    //var_dump(preg_replace('/created_date/','\"26-09-2016\"', $value_in_format));
    echo nl2br('<br/>');
    echo nl2br('<br/>');
    eval("echo $value_in_format;");
    echo nl2br('<br/>');
    echo nl2br('<br/>');
}
?>
```

Comment: i want to run the php date function to get the second parameter value from preg_replace.  but it was display in string format like  date('Y-m-d',strtotime(26-09-2016))

Comment: It is displayed in string format because is wrong defined in array:  this:            array('format'=>"date('Y-m-d',strtotime(created_date))");      should be:         array('format'=>date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Ymd")));

Comment: but i want to set strtotime() value from preg_replace

Comment: I updated the answer and used eval() function that allows you to execute strings which contains php code.